# Построчное сравнение данных из столбца функцией def

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Нужно после загрузки котировки, построчно проверить (в нашем случае 10 дней), находится ли цена открытия `Open` на дату 2017-01-01 выше 5% от цены или ниже 5% от цены. Например `Open = 100`, проверяем первую строку данных, правда ли, что `High < 100 + (100 * 5%)`, а `Low > 100 - (100 * 5%)`. Если верно первое пишем `print(High)`, если второе `print(Low)`. Если оба удовлетворяют условию - предпочтение отдаем `Low` и делаем `print(Low)`. Если не то, не другое, то проверяем следующую строку данных и так пока не закончатся данные.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime 

df = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-10')
def
```

Comment: А в чем проблема с проверками? Ваш код, кстати, содержит синтаксическую ошибку и не будет выполнен - ключевое слово def - это объявление функции, а самого тела, названия и параметров у вас нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь вложенным [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) методом:

```
In [47]: df = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-26')

In [48]: d = 0.005  # я специально взял 0.5% вместо 5%, чтобы в срезе были все три случая

In [49]: df['new'] = \
    ...: np.where(
    ...:     df.Low > df.Open * (1 - d),
    ...:     df.Low,
    ...:     np.where(df.High < df.Open * (1 + d),
    ...:         df.High,
    ...:         np.nan
    ...:     )
    ...: )
    ...:
```

Результат:

Low > Open * 0.995:

```
In [58]: df.loc[df.new == df.Low, ['Open','High','Low','new']]
Out[58]:
                  Open        High         Low         new
Date
2017-01-04  115.849998  116.510002  115.750000  115.750000
2017-01-05  115.919998  116.860001  115.809998  115.809998
2017-01-06  116.779999  118.160004  116.470001  116.470001
2017-01-09  117.949997  119.430000  117.940002  117.940002
2017-01-10  118.769997  119.379997  118.300003  118.300003
2017-01-11  118.739998  119.930000  118.599998  118.599998
2017-01-13  119.110001  119.620003  118.809998  118.809998
2017-01-17  118.339996  120.239998  118.220001  118.220001
2017-01-18  120.000000  120.500000  119.709999  119.709999
2017-01-19  119.400002  120.089996  119.370003  119.370003
...                ...         ...         ...         ...
2017-02-07  130.539993  132.089996  130.449997  130.449997
2017-02-08  131.350006  132.220001  131.220001  131.220001
2017-02-09  131.649994  132.449997  131.119995  131.119995
2017-02-10  132.460007  132.940002  132.050003  132.050003
2017-02-13  133.080002  133.820007  132.750000  132.750000
2017-02-14  133.470001  135.089996  133.250000  133.250000
2017-02-17  135.100006  135.830002  135.100006  135.100006
2017-02-21  136.229996  136.750000  135.979996  135.979996
2017-02-22  136.429993  137.119995  136.110001  136.110001
2017-02-24  135.910004  136.660004  135.279999  135.279999

[31 rows x 4 columns]
```

High < Open * 1.005:

```
In [59]: df.loc[df.new == df.High, ['Open','High','Low','new']]
Out[59]:
                  Open        High         Low         new
Date
2017-01-03  115.800003  116.330002  114.760002  116.330002
2017-01-12  118.900002  119.300003  118.209999  119.300003
2017-01-20  120.449997  120.449997  119.730003  120.449997
2017-02-16  135.669998  135.899994  134.839996  135.899994
2017-02-23  137.380005  137.479996  136.300003  137.479996
```

не выполнено ни одно из условий:

```
In [60]: df.loc[df.new.isnull(), ['Open','High','Low','new']]
Out[60]:
                  Open        High         Low  new
Date
2017-02-15  135.520004  136.270004  134.619995  NaN
```